# Computer loses network connection every 33 hours

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, firefox

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad laptop running Windows 7, and my primary browser is Firefox 75.0. Recently, I noticed that my computer would intermittently stop connecting to the Internet, and would need to be restarted in order to get it working again. The Internet connection comes from a wifi network that several other devices in the house have been connected to throughout all of this with no problems at all. I have also noticed that the loss of connection is extremely regular and predictable: exactly 1 day, 9 hours, and 3 minutes after the computer is restarted, I will no longer be able to open new tabs or click on links in Firefox (or Internet Explorer, for that matter). I can still use the Internet through pages that are already open, such as Google Docs, but about 15-20 minutes later, these stop working as well and my computer drops to zero bandwidth.

The loss of connection is so precisely scheduled that I could set my watch to it. It also seems to be based on uptime, not clock time: once, I left my laptop off the charger for too long and it went into power-save mode. A few hours later, I woke it back up, and then later that day, it lost connection – not 33 hours after the last restart, as I had expected, but 33 hours plus the amount of time it was asleep. Does anyone know what might possibly cause a problem like this?

Comment: Update your wireless driver to a current version. This will also reset TCP/IP and DNS.  Check with RealTemp the operating temperature of your ThinkPad - especially 32 and 33 hours later. The Wireless Card could be overheating. Try a USB Wireless card to see if that is any better.

Comment: What's the model number of the Thinkpad?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It's a ThinkPad E560 (20EV002FUS).

Comment: What does windows report your card as? It looks like these were sent out with multiple different models of wireless adapters.

Comment: Under Network Adapters in Device Manager, I see "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165", "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter", and "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2", alongside the Bluetooth and Ethernet drivers. On the advice of @John I tried updating all of these. The Intel one said it was up to date, but I was able to update the other two. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Try then running TCP/IP Reset:   
Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer
See if the reset / flush fixes the issue

Comment: You mean having windows search & update it?

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded recently, since I can only tell whether one of your suggestions has worked after 33 hours. I tried every suggestion except the TCP/IP Reset earlier today, and it still lost connection when it was expected to. Before restarting the computer this time, I followed the TCP/IP Reset process, so on Friday morning I will know whether that worked. I will keep you updated.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of any update. I had to restart my computer twice for unrelated reasons over the weekend and was unable to see whether the TCP/IP Reset @John suggested had worked until this morning. Unfortunately, the problem still remains. Anyone have other suggestions?